# Permission Denied in admin custom page opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

**I followed Below procedure But still i m getting permission denied error .
I am using opencart 2.x**

1) Create a new file in admin/controller/custom/helloworld.php

Your filename and controller name should be the same in desc order:

helloworld.php

```
<?

    class ControllerCustomHelloWorld extends Controller{ 
        public function index(){
                    // VARS
                    $template="custom/hello.tpl"; // .tpl location and file
            $this->load->model('custom/hello');
            $this->template = ''.$template.'';
            $this->children = array(
                'common/header',
                'common/footer'
            );      
            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        }
    }
    ?>
```

2) Create a new file in admin/view/template/custom/hello.tpl

```
Hello.tpl



 <?php echo $header; ?>
    <div id="content">
    <h1>HelloWorld</h1>
    <?php
    echo 'I can also run PHP too!'; 
    ?>
    </div> 
    <?php echo $footer; ?>
```

3) Create a new file in admin/model/custom/hello.php

```
  <?php
    class ModelCustomHello extends Model {
        public function HellWorld() {
            $sql = "SELECT x FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "y`)"; 
            $implode = array();
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->row['total'];    
        }       
    }

?>
```

4) You then need to enable the plugin to avoid permission denied errors:

Opencart > Admin > Users > User Groups > Admin > Edit
Select and Enable the Access Permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the way add custom helloworld module in admin

1. create `admin/controller/custom/helloworld.php`

   ```
   <?php
   class ControllerCustomHelloworld extends Controller {

    public function index() {

    $this->load->language('custom/helloworld');
    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
    $this->load->model('custom/helloworld');        

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('custom/helloworld.tpl', $data));

    }
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. Create `admin/model/custom/helloworld.php`

   ```
   <?php
   class ModelCustomHelloworld extends Model {

   public function helloworldmodel(){

    }
   }
   ?>
   ```
3. create `admin/language/english/custom/helloworld.php`

   ```
   <?php
   // Heading
   $_['heading_title']          = 'Hello world Admin module';

   ?>
   ```
4. Create `admin/view/template/custom/helloworld.tpl`

   ```
   <?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
   <h1><?php echo "This is helloworld admin module in opencart 2.x.x.x "; ?></h1>         
   <?php echo $footer; ?>
   ```
5. Go to `system -> users -> user groups -> edit Administrator group`. Select all to `access permission` and `modify permission` and save.[image]

Here is the tutorial http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2015/12/17/create-custom-module-in-opencart-admin/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look into following URLs for the resolution-

[Step by step process to create a custom Admin page in Opencart](http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-create-a-custom-admin-page-in-opencart/)

[Fixing the permission error](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-permission-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-this-page-error.html)

I hope above links will help you.

Comment: I checked all access permission in user group . Still its showing error . Can you send me all code once .